# How do I unlock weapon patterns for crafting?

Tags: destiny-2

I have a quest which requires me to craft weapons. However I can't find the patterns for them, nor do I know how to unlock the patterns.

[image: Come to Pass shaped, Tarnation shaped]

How do I unlock patterns for crafting during Season 16: Season of the Risen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To acquire a weapon pattern for crafting, you must get a number of them to drop with Deepsight Resonance (aka the "red border") and complete their progress bar under the weapon's description.

Once progress has been completed, you can acquire the resources from Deepsight Resonance for the weapon. **One of the resources collected here is the weapon pattern for future crafting.**

Most of the crafting patterns require multiple completions of Deepsight Resonance for these weapons. You can find your progress on these crafting templates under the Collections tab of your inventory, under the same section as where Exotic Catalysts are listed.

Of particular relevance for this question, the weapons listed in the quest are generally dropped from the Wellspring activity, which rotates the weapon daily. It is still a random drop, and generally the drop with Deepsight is rarer, but Bungie has recently made changes that should improve the drop rate.

*Edit,*
Some weapons drop with an unlockable pattern, which replaces the Deepsight Resonance.

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that since the Lightfall expansion (Feb 2023) red border weapon patterns can simply be collected from the weapon immediately